# Elixir's :binary.bin_to_list atom is not working properly

Tags: elixir

I am trying to create a simple app for creating Identicons.

`Hash.input` should return first 3 values from a list, but it breaks when I try to hash `'hello'`. What is going on and how can I fix it?

```
defmodule Hash do
    def input(input) do
        hex = :crypto.hash(:md5, input) |> IO.inspect |> :binary.bin_to_list
        [first, second, third | _tail] = hex
        [first, second, third]
    end
end
```

Code output:

```
iex(1)> Hash.input('hello')
<<93, 65, 64, 42, 188, 75, 42, 118, 185, 113, 157, 145, 16, 23, 197, 146>>
']A@'

iex(2)> Hash.input('good day') 
<<202, 151, 104, 189, 8, 195, 115, 102, 95, 188, 200, 128, 33, 240, 136, 182>>
[202, 151, 104]
```

Comment: What does mean “it breaks”? It works exactly as intended, the same as `:binary.bin_to_list/1`. What have you wanted to get back?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `def input(input), do: :crypto.hash(:md5, input) |> :binary.bin_to_list() |> Enum.take(3)`.